# Java, comparing objects

Tags: java, operators, overloading

Sorry, I'm a real beginner in Java, so this question probably already has an answer, but I wasn't able to find it.
I want to do something equivalent to (I already know you can't actually overload operators):

```
bool operator < (MyClass a, MyClass b) {/*code*/}
```

What is the required syntax to do so, and where do I define this operation?

Answer (score 4):

Have `MyClass` implement `Comparable`:

```
class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass> {
   public int compareTo(MyClass other) {
     // returns a negative number if this < other, 0 if this == other,
     // a positive number if this > other
   }
}
```

and then to say `a < b`, write `a.compareTo(b) < 0`.

Alternatively, to impose an "external ordering," write a `Comparator`:

```
Comparator<MyClass> comparator = new Comparator<MyClass>() {
  public int compare(MyClass a, MyClass b) {
    // same rules
  }
};
```

and then do `comparator.compare(a, b) < 0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for equality then you need to override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `MyClass` . Then you can check as `a.equals(b)`.

If you want to compare them , then you can implement `Comparable` in `MyClass` .

If you want to compare based on different fields then write a `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

java doesn't support operator overloading like you want. You can create a method to compare specific values of objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are two interfaces for something like this in Java: [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

`Comparable` is for comparaing `this` with another object while `Comparator` is used for comparing two other objects.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to implement methods to compare. This should be done by implementing `Comparable`.

```
public class MyClass implements Comparable
{
    public int compareTo(Object o)
    {
        // Compare code
    }
}
```

This method must return 0 if the objects are the same (for example, "myString" and "myString), a negative number if this object is less than the one we're comparing it to (for example, "aaa" and "bbb"), and a positive number if this object is greater than the one we're comparing it to (for example, "ccc" and "bbb").

Note that it doesn't have to, nor should it be expected, that the negative and positive number is going to be one or negative one. It simply has to be negative or positive. For example, we could return an offset, which would be more specific in telling us how two objects compare.